# Ember.js QUnit Test Only Visible Elements With find()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

I'm trying to TDD my first Ember app. I want to display one `<article>` element at a time. I'm getting several articles from the server. My show view defines `isVisible()` so that only one `<article>` is displayed to the user at a time.

In my test, I want to do something like:

`equal(find('article').text(), 'foobar');`

The problem is that it finds all the articles whether they're visible or not.

I'm fairly new to Ember so I have some ideas of what to do from here but none seems ideal.

I could look for the enclosing `<div id="embernnn" class="ember-view>` tags and reject the instances where Ember has applied the inline `display:none` style. But that would rely on the implementation rather than the abstraction.

I could use the view to add a class to the current `<article>` but if I have to do that then why would Ember provide the isVisible property in the View?

I'm guessing there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use inline styles--use CSS classes instead.  In your view/component, just add `classNameBindings: ['isVisible'],`, and in your CSS you can use `.is-visible { display: block; }`.  I would actually invert the logic on that, as something should be visible unless hidden, instead of hidden unless visible, but I think you get my general point.

In your test case, you can assert that the element has the desired class, or select the active article with `find('article.is-visible')`.

Comment: Thanks @mpowered. That makes sense. It just feels funny that Ember lets me define isVisible() on the View if I can't test it easily? Also, shouldn't the classNameBindings go in the view instead of the controller as you suggested? I agree that visible unless hidden is best.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke because I have a tendency to use components for nearly everything.  I really only use the application view these days, and use components for everything else.  Sorry if I was unclear :-)

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to keep the record here clear. I'm not sure where I got the idea of defining isVisible() in the view. It works as desired by automatically adding the inline style of display:none to the enclosing embernnn elements as described in my question. But if there isn't good test support then I will go with your answer.

Comment: There is a very very large case made for declaring your elements' semantics with classes, as it encourages consistency across your UIs.  It's generally supported to define what something _is_ and not what it _looks like_.  In this case, I would argue that your `article` is `active`, and let the CSS determine how that should look.  In capybara, for instance, one would get the DOM ID of the article in question and assert that it has the proper class, which makes testing very explicit, deliberate, and clear.

Comment: Very good point. I think I just got thrown off by the ability to set isVisible() as I was learning the Ember way.